# azure app service in node JWT signature validation fialed

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, jwt, azure-authentication

getting this error for my azure app service (using node), when doing google authentication:
`PID[8116] Warning     JWT validation failed: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Key tried: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey'.`

Not sure where to go from here. Any help appreciated!

Comment: who is generating the token? azure ad?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue starting last night with an azure mobile app service on .Net:

```
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Warning: 0 :
JWT validation failed: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. 
Key tried: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey'.

token: '{"alg":"RS256","kid":"fdcaa63240ed28eae381d1643d4cc9356dc397eb"}
```

I have not found a solution, but right not it seems to me, as if it is somehow related to the `kid`. The error (*to me, currently*) only seems to occur, when the `kid` for the `id_token` is the one from the error message and not one of the other 3 from [here](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs).

Can you confirm if that's the case for you too?